# How does Cufon affect SEO and Search Bots?

Tags: image, seo, cufon

I've been searching the web and can't find an answer to the question
of how using Cufon affects SEO (the way bots from Google, Bing,
Yahoo... read the page).  I know the original text is still there, but
it is inside a  tag, inside a  tag, and is next to
a  tag (instead of next to the word that should be next to
it).  In other words, do the search bots read "search by", the same
way they'd read the cufon generated html below?

```
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="search" style="width: 72px;
height: 28.1667px;">
<canvas width="95" height="28" style="width: 95px; height: 28px; top:
0px; left: -5px;"/>
<cufontext>search</cufontext>
</cufon>
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" by:" style="width: 36px;
height: 28.1667px;">
<canvas width="68" height="28" style="width: 68px; height: 28px; top:
0px; left: -5px;"/>
<cufontext> by:</cufontext>
</cufon>
```

I really like cufon since I'm not much of a graphics guy, but I also
don't want to ruin any good SEO I've got going.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice,
Chuck Foster

Answer (score 20):

**Cufon does not affect SEO at all**. Its rendering engine is written in Javascript, and search engines don't read Javascript.

The code snippet you posted is what HTML looks like in your browser **after** Cufon has done its job; the search engines will only see your original html (the one you view when you click on *View > Page Source* in Firefox for instance).

Comment: This isn't correct - Google started processing Javascript at least 12 months ago

Comment: @Dr Rob: Ok, but to what extent? And what could be Google's interest in parsing & showing in its SERPS ugly cufon-processed text?

Comment: I am simply stating that the assertion "Search engines don't read Javascript" is incorrect. This does not mean that it processes Cufon text - in fact if you Google "Katie Perry Homepage" and then view the new Google Page Preview you will see that it doesn't process the Cufon text as the preview does not include any of the menu or heading text. So this actually raises a completely separate issue regarding Cufon and Google.

Comment: @DrRob: Google the same text and see the preview for "Tour Dates" you can see those small section headers like "News", "Videos", "Photos" those all are cufon text. So i think, even though google can process javascript, it doesnt affect cufon text.

Comment: A little experiment [by someone in 2011](http://www.aerodesigns.co.uk/blog/negative-seo-effects-of-cufon/) suggests that it does not affect SEO. I would be cautious to say it doesn't affect it at all even with this small experiment.

Answer (score 4):

A handy tip I learned while reading up on Google SEO is to take a look at your page in a text-viewer to give you a sense of what's visible to Google. You can do that with this handy tool: http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/lynx/lynx_viewer.php
Notice how your cufon shows up just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically Cufon shouldn't affect search rankings as it is rendered after the page loads by Javascript. The actual source code still contains the heading. Despite this I found that there were quite a few conflicting opinions about the search-friendliness of Cufon so I've done a small study to try and get some data on whether it does actually affect rankings, here it is: [Cufon SEO Effects](http://www.aerodesigns.co.uk/blog/negative-seo-effects-of-cufon/)

The study finds that Cufon doesn't have any direct effect on search rankings, although you could argue that the marginal increase in a page load time on a site that includes the Cufon Javascript file could potentially affect rankings, although in my opinion this difference would be minor.

Answer (score 0):

No SEO impact at all. Much better than sFIR IMO for two reasons. 1. Faster, 2. Simplicity

Answer (score 0):

I have found a great article which will prove there is no "negative seo" in cufon..

http://www.aerodesigns.co.uk/blog/negative-seo-effects-of-cufon/

Thanks..